# Lost data after turn off Android application

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, graph

I lost data from my graph when I turn off app. How to save array with data for next usage? I am also new in Android app programming. I had created class with name XYvalues so don't be confused, that class is not important now for us I think.

Code:

```
public class graph extends AppCompatActivity {
private  static  final String TAG = "graph";
PointsGraphSeries<DataPoint> xySeries;
private Button btnAddPt;
private EditText mX,mY;
GraphView mScatterPlot;
private ArrayList <XYValues> xyValuesArray;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_graph);
    btnAddPt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnAddPt);
    mX = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numX);
    mY = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numY);
    mScatterPlot = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.scatterPlot);
    xyValuesArray = new ArrayList<>();
    init();
}
private  void init() {
    xySeries = new PointsGraphSeries<>();
    btnAddPt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!mX.getText().toString().equals("") && !mY.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                double x = Double.parseDouble(mX.getText().toString());
                double y = Double.parseDouble(mY.getText().toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Adding a new point. (x,y)(" + x + "," + y + ")");
                xyValuesArray.add(new XYValues(x, y));
                init();
            } else


            {
                toastMessage("You must fill both fields");
            }
        }


    });

    if (xyValuesArray.size() != 0) {
        createScatterPlot();

    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: No data to plot");

    }
}
private void createScatterPlot(){
    Log.d(TAG, "createScatterPlot:Creating scatter plot.");
    xyValuesArray = sortArray(xyValuesArray);
    for (int i =0; i<xyValuesArray.size();i++){
        try{
            double x = xyValuesArray.get(i).getX();
            double y = xyValuesArray.get(i).getY();
            xySeries.appendData(new DataPoint(x,y),true,1000);

        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){


            Log.e(TAG, "createScatterPlot:IllegalArgumentException: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    xySeries.setShape(PointsGraphSeries.Shape.POINT);
    xySeries.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    xySeries.setSize(20f);

    mScatterPlot.getViewport().setScalable(true);
    mScatterPlot.getViewport().setScalableY(true);
    mScatterPlot.getViewport().setScrollable(true);
    mScatterPlot.getViewport().setScrollableY(true);

    mScatterPlot.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
    mScatterPlot.getViewport().setMaxY(250);
    mScatterPlot.getViewport().setMinY(0);

    mScatterPlot.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
    mScatterPlot.getViewport().setMaxX(3000);
    mScatterPlot.getViewport().setMinX(0);

    mScatterPlot.addSeries(xySeries);
}

private  ArrayList<XYValues> sortArray(ArrayList<XYValues>array){
    int factor = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Math.round(Math.pow(array.size(),2))));
    int m = array.size() - 1;
    int count =0;
    Log.d(TAG,"sortArray:Sorting XYarray");
    while (true){
        m--;
        if(m<=0){
            m=array.size()-1;
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"SortArray: m =" +m);
        try{
            double tempY = array.get(m-1).getY();
            double tempX = array.get(m-1).getX();
            if (tempX>array.get(m).getX()){
                array.get(m-1).setY(array.get(m).getY());
                array.get(m).setY(tempY);
                array.get(m-1).setX(array.get(m).getX());
                array.get(m).setX(tempX);
            }
            else if (tempX ==array.get(m).getX()){
                count++;
                Log.d(TAG,"sortArray: count = "+count);

            }
            else if (array.get(m).getX()>array.get(m-1).getX()){
                count++;
                Log.d(TAG,"sortArray: count = "+count);
            }
            if (count == factor){
                break;
            }
        }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            Log.e(TAG,"sortArray: ArrayIndexOutBoundsException. Need more than 1 data to create plot = "+e.getMessage());
            break;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
private void toastMessage (String message){
    Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

Comment: You'll need to learn how to use the Preferences API (and probably the Parcelable API as well). It's not too complex but its the bare minimum if you need to store persistent data in Android.

Comment: try little study on this realm.io/docs/java/latest Its really simple and fast. Or try serialization.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the graph data before your app is closed and read the data back from storage next time your app is started.

How to best store the data depends on how much data it is.

If its only a little data I suggest using the [Preference API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Other storage options can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: try little study on this https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/



Its really simple and fast. 

Or try serialization.

Comment: @trip08: you are welcome to post your link as a reply to another answer, but would it not be better addressed to the question author, underneath his/her question?